# GitHub Personal Access Token Get Expiry

Tags: github

Given a currently valid GitHub personal access token, is there an API endpoint to retrieve the expiry date of the token?

I'd like to build a script which checks my expiry date and notifies me when the token will expire the following day.

Comment: I dont think there is an API endpoint for tokens, but GitHub sends an email if your token is about to expire

Answer (score 3):

GitHub [recently announced](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-07-26-expiration-options-for-personal-access-tokens/) the `GitHub-Authentication-Token-Expiration` header being returned in all API responses which includes the value in this format `2021-10-07 19:07:53 UTC`.

I validated this using this request via HTTPie:

```
http https://api.github.com/graphql "Authorization: Bearer ghp_xxx" 'Content-Type: application/graphql' 'Accept: application/vnd.github.merge-info-preview+json' query='{__schema { directives { description name}}}
```